# Concatenation of ObjectId and string in django template

Tags: python, html, django

I have a very simple question, on which i spent hours.
Heres the deal: i insert a path to an image in mongodb, save said image in my static folder (under objectId.png) and pass the objectId to my template in order to display it.

Heres some code, in views:

```
return render(request,'resultat_simulation.html',{'truc':truc2})
```

truc2=str(truc.id), truc being the object inserted in the DB.

It is passed to the template without issue.

Now, the template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block body %}
{{truc}}
<img src="{% static 'C:\Users\smeca\Documents\projetfinal\stage\app\static\images\{{truc}}.png' %}"> 
{% endblock %}
```

If instead of {{truc}}, i put the ObjectId of any image, it is rendered.
I just want to append the string form of objectid to '.png' so i can loop through the images and display them all.
I tried everything i found on the net to no avail.

Thanks in advance.

```
{% with 'stage/app/static/images/'|add:truc|add:".png" as image_static %}
{{image_static}}
<img src="{% static image_static %}">
{% endwith %}
```

{{image_static}} returns .png

Solution :

Finally i straight up passed the path to the template

```
return render(request,'resultat_simulation.html',{'image_path':'/images/' + str(truc2) + '.png'})
```

and loaded it with `{% static image_path %}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use a variable with double brackets `{{ }}` inside template logic `{% %}`.

The workaround in order to use a variable along a static tag is to use the [`add` tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#add):

```
{% with "first/part/of/your/path"|add:truc|add:".png" as image_static %}
    <img src="{% static image_static %}">
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Its clearly on the right track, though image_static only gets '.png'. Its like the first part of the string isnt parsed. I edited my post

Comment: It's working fine for me and the code does not need anything else to work. What is your static path ? If you print truc, is it as expected ? Check there is no additional space inbetween your "add" and use the same kind of " " for all your strings... even if i doubt it changes anything...